# calling d3.json from non root-URL

Tags: django, d3.js

I have a problem calling the json function from d3.

From a page that renders a model in my Django DB (this website is called from this url '/app/function/pk') I call in JS d3.json in order to use some data using "app/dootherthing/pk" as url. E.g: d3.json("/app/dootherthing/pk"). however, the console in developer mode gives me an error since d3.json tries to get the json object from http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/function/pk/app/dootherthing/pk instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/dootherthing/pk that is where this json object is.

How can I redirect the d3.json to the root url "127.0.0.1:8000/" and not use the current url as root anymore?

I dont know if I am explained myself but I guess it should be something stupid and easy, thanks for your answers!

Best.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant JS code?

Comment: d3.json("app/dootherthing/" + pk, function (error, graph) {
    force(graph);

    if (error) throw error;
});

Comment: This works if I call it from http://127.0.0.1:8000/ but not when I am in the url "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/function/pk" since the function d3.json tries this url "app/function/pk/app/dootherthing/pk"

Answer (score 0):

You are supplying a relativ path, trying changing it to an absolute path

```
"/app/dootherthing/"
```

or alternatively

```
"../../app/dootherthing/"
```

---

You can always check the current URL/path with `window.location.href`, e.g.

```
var app_url = "app/dootherthing";
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/app/') !== -1) {
    url = window.location.href.slice(0, window.location.href.indexOf('/app/')) + '/' + app_url;
} else {
    url = app_url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I am using the same html and javascript for a similar approach so I would like to use both html/js also here. In this approach it works because it is called from the root url. I wonder if it makes sense to create a conditional and depending on where I am call the relative paths that I think it will work.